# Effective and good looking crontab

Tags: cron

I am working in a telecommunication company. When I started, there is already a system(HP-UX) . But now there is a new system(RedHat) and I am responsible for the system.

We use crontab for the controls. The old system's crontab is not looking good. It's too messy. I can say that it's a chaos.

We're at the beginning on the new system and I want to use crontab more effectively. I want to make it more organized and good looking.

Do you have any suggestions? How do you use your crontab?

I want to give an example that we use.

```
15, 45 * * * * ksh(bahs or sh also) /path to script/script.sh >>(or>) /path to log file/logfile_`date`_(sometimes hostname).log
```

I am not too professional but I want to be more professional than the older members of the team. And if I leave here tomorrow, I want to leave an easy-to-learn-and-use system here.

Not only for crontab, but also every suggestions of you are valuable for me here.

Basically we use oracle database and shell scripts to control, monitor and automate something.

I researched but couldn't find anything that works for me about this. I hope I didn't ask a wrong thing.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There are myriad improvements you could make; I'd recommend doing some research on "cron best practices", such as:

- Put the tasks in their own shell script file (use `/etc/crontab.d/` rather than `/etc/crontab` and friends)

  - Use version control
- Use file locking to prevent concurrent invocations
- Include appropriate timeouts
- For tasks that could run at the same time as on other systems', sleep for a random delay to mitigate the [thundering herd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem)
- Apply the principle of least privilege - use root only when required
- Set mail handling/etc correctly so that mail from cron is delivered to the right place

  - Don't rely on email to know when things are broken - use centralised logging
- Be aware that the environment cron runs in is not the same as your interactive shell

  - Create and use tests
- Don’t throw away errors or *useful* output

  - Send the output somewhere useful, e.g. centralised logging